# How can I achieve filtering by another taxonomy (e.g. 'ticket status') from a common post type within a taxonomy archive (e.g. 'sprint')?

Tags: wordpress

**The problem**: I'm currently using Oxygen Builder to create a public kanban board / Trello-like webpage where the posts have a status (To-do, Doing, Done) and those changes are shown on the homepage. I intended to use Repeater for this, but the following problem arose.

I have created a new post type (called 'ticket' in my case). This post type has its own taxonomies ('assignee', 'sprint' and 'status'). I use CPT to create a ticket and I pick the taxonomies when I create the ticket.

In Oxygen I have created templates for the archive of 'Sprint' page taxonomies and created columns for the three statuses - 'To-do, Doing, Done'. In the To-do column I put Repeater and found out that I could filter by taxonomies status = 'To-do', but getting the result of all such posts on the whole website. But I only need Repeater to search for posts with taxonomy 'To-do' for a particular 'Sprint' taxonomy archive page.

I would be grateful if you could offer your ideas on how to implement a similar idea on Oxygen.

Comment: What do you mean by Repeaters ? Do you mean a custom loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing repeater in your question, here, means loop. You should use the [`WP_Query` taxonomy parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) to fetch the appropriate posts.

> - {tax} (string) – use taxonomy slug. (Deprecated since version 3.1 in favor of ‘tax_query‘).
> - tax_query (array) – use taxonomy parameters (available since version 3.1).
> - relation (string) – The logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one. Possible values are ‘AND’, ‘OR’. Do not use with a single inner taxonomy array.
> - taxonomy (string) – Taxonomy.
> - field (string) – Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are ‘term_id’, ‘name’, ‘slug’ or ‘term_taxonomy_id’. Default value is ‘term_id’.
> - terms (int/string/array) – Taxonomy term(s).
>   include_children (boolean) – Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.
> - operator (string) – Operator to test. Possible values are ‘IN’, ‘NOT IN’, ‘AND’, ‘EXISTS’ and ‘NOT EXISTS’. Default value is ‘IN’.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

We can then build our custom query.

```
<?php
// Column To-Do
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'ticket',
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'tax_query' => [[
    'taxonomy' => 'status',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => [ 'to-do', ], // ... replace "to-do" by "doing" or "done" for the other columns
    ]],
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ):
  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```